# A/V Stuttering During Media Streaming/Gaming Wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, gaming, video-streaming

I am running a generic PCIe based 2.4GHz Wifi adapter on my PC build and every time I use my *wireless* network random A/V stuttering occurs.

I checked that my drivers were up to date and they were. Also when I use an ethernet connection my issues dissipate.

How can I fix the A/V glitching/artifacting I am experiencing?

Comment: @Div What about it?

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using my PCIe based WiFi adapter and opted for a **USB WiFi adapter instead** to mitigate electromagnetic interference the PCIe card may have been putting on my GPU and all of my issues went away. Now I am able to stream video/play network demanding online games with reliability comparable to my previous ethernet connection set up.

Comment: The problem with the PCIe adapter was more likely the poor placement of its antenna than EMI affecting the GPU.

Comment: @sawdust The adapter I had installed used two rotatable antenna, but changing the orientation of them did not fix any of the A/V issues the adapter was causing.

Comment: Did you also try moving the PC case so that the backside of the PC faced the wireless router or WAP?